# found integer in text data with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I have a database table,in one Column I have data Like:

```
id      tags
1       1.2,2.2,22.2
2       20.1,30.1,45.2,46.0,55.3 
3       1.3,6.1,7.2,9.4,10.2
```

I want to search ids having num 1 in tag's Column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**LIKE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) operator to search the data

```
SELECT id 
FROM tableA 
WHERE tags LIKE '%1%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another using `INSTR` when wildcard is on both sides in a `LIKE` search!

```
SELECT id
FROM tableA
WHERE INSTR(tags,'1') > 0 ;
```

Comment: Why INSTR? Which Best INSTR or LIKE

Comment: in your case both are same! when you expect the letter to be in x location, INSTR wins. LIKE wins, when the wildcard is given only at end.